# ElasticSearch Querystring Query Wildcard on query with multiple tokens

Tags: elasticsearch, wildcard

For example I have a record with the contents "FileV2UpdateRequest" and based on my analyzer it would break the record into tokens:

- filev
- 2
- updaterequest

I want to be able to search `filev2update*` in the "query_string" query to find it but for whatever reason the `*` doesn't try to find the rest of 'updaterequest' like it should.

If I enter the query `filev2 update*` it returns the results.

Is there anything I can do to make that work where the space isn't needed?

I have tried using auto_generate_phrase_queries set to true but that also isn't working to solve the issue. It seems like when you add the wildcard symbol it looks at the entire input as one token rather than just looking at the token the wildcard is touching.

If I add analyze_wildcard and set it to true, it tries to put the * on every token in the query. costv* 2* add*

Answer (score 0):

I think you can change index **filter** by using [**word_delimiter**](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/2.0/analysis-word-delimiter-tokenfilter.html) to index your content, [Compound Word Token Filter](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-compound-word-tokenfilter.html)

if use this **filter**,

**FileV2UpdateRequest** will be analysised to tokens:

```
{
    "tokens": [{
        "token": "File",
        "start_offset": 0,
        "end_offset": 4,
        "type": "word",
        "position": 1
    }, {
        "token": "V",
        "start_offset": 4,
        "end_offset": 5,
        "type": "word",
        "position": 2
    }, {
        "token": "2",
        "start_offset": 5,
        "end_offset": 6,
        "type": "word",
        "position": 3
    }, {
        "token": "Update",
        "start_offset": 6,
        "end_offset": 12,
        "type": "word",
        "position": 4
    }, {
        "token": "Request",
        "start_offset": 12,
        "end_offset": 19,
        "type": "word",
        "position": 5
    }]
}
```

and for search content you also need use **word_delimiter** as **filter** without using **wild_card**.

**filev2update** will be analysised to tokens:

```
{
    "tokens": [{
        "token": "file",
        "start_offset": 0,
        "end_offset": 4,
        "type": "word",
        "position": 1
    }, {
        "token": "V",
        "start_offset": 4,
        "end_offset": 5,
        "type": "word",
        "position": 2
    }, {
        "token": "2",
        "start_offset": 5,
        "end_offset": 6,
        "type": "word",
        "position": 3
    }, {
        "token": "update",
        "start_offset": 6,
        "end_offset": 12,
        "type": "word",
        "position": 4
    }]
}
```

Comment: I do have some cases where i have an example like File_V2_Update and I want the _ to matter in searches...wouldn't word delimiter ignore those?

Comment: it will ignore _, but why do you want to search _?

Comment: because if i have File_V2_Update and FileV2Update i want them to be distinguishable